# Invoke dataflow pipeline error in app engine

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to schedule the dataflow pipeline as per [Scheduling Dataflow pipelines using App Engine Cron Service or Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/04/scheduling-dataflow-pipelines-using-app-engine-cron-service-or-cloud-functions).

When run, my pipeline throws an exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRHT3.png) of an error message.

**Maven project one (app engine):**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.42</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    project two 
</dependency>
```

**Maven project two:**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
  <version>[1.6.0, 2.0.0)</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.22.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Do I need this dependency,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

or this one?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-archetypes-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more stack trace? The reason as to why PipelineOptionsFactory failed to initialize is buried in the ...

Comment: Google Cloud Dataflow requires you to use an AppEngine flex (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) environment. Are you using an AppEngine flex environment?

Comment: You want to depend on google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all. google-cloud-dataflow-java-archetypes-starter is a Maven template that creates a starter project for you. See Maven archetypes (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html) for more details.

Comment: @dave Is this resolved?